# Not clear on how a simple vector subtraction was opened up to a summation.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, summation, gradient-descent

As part of a derivation, I have the following derivation. I understand the whole thing, but I do not understand how the author went from the first line here, to the second line. Can someone please elucidate how they did that?

He basically seems to have "opened up" the $\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_i$ term, but I am not clear how that translates to what is written in the second line.

Context: The formula comes from a derivation [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/TUZEL1/MeanShift.pdf)

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Let's try this again. We have 
\begin{align*}
\nabla f(\mathbf{x})&=\frac{2c}{nh^{d+2}}\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{x_i}-\mathbf{x})g(\cdot)\\
&=\frac{2c}{nh^{d+2}}\sum_{i=1}^n\Big(\mathbf{x_i}g(\cdot)-\mathbf{x}g(\cdot)\Big)\;\;\text{distributing g}\\
&=\frac{2c}{nh^{d+2}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x_i}g(\cdot)-\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}g(\cdot)\right)\;\;\text{ break into two sums}\\
&=\frac{2c}{nh^{d+2}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x_i}g(\cdot)-\mathbf{x}\sum_{i=1}^ng(\cdot)\right)\;\;\text{pull out x}\\
&=\frac{2c}{nh^{d+2}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^ng(\cdot)\right)\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x_i}g(\cdot)}{\sum_{i=1}^ng(\cdot)}-\mathbf{x}\right)\;\;\text{ factor out the sum of just g}
\end{align*}

Comment: @Spacey I can't say much more about this without some more context (and even with more context, I don't know much about gaussian functions). All I can say is that the author probably moved the $\mathbf{x_i}$ inside the summation *because that worked in the current derivation that they were working on*. Since $\mathbf{x_i}$ does not depend on the index of summation it is perfectly fine to put it wherever works best for the proof, just as I can write $5\cdot(3+x)=(5\cdot3+5\cdot x)$.

Comment: Wait...but $x_i$ *does* depend on the index of summation...

Comment: @Spacey You're right, I did not look closely enough at the second sum. I will delete this, but before I do so, would you mind posting some more context for the problem? It is hard to read the author's intent just by looking at two equalities

Comment: Thanks - and I just edited the question with a link to the context.

Comment: @Spacey It should be fixed now I hope. Let me know if you need any more clarification

Comment: Perfecto. Thank you! I wish papers were more explicit in this type of stuff.